# Angular Storybook - How to use a service with dependencies in a story without creating a separate component?

Tags: angular, typescript, storybook, angular-storybook

I'm working on a Storybook project where I have a component (**ToastersComponent**) used only for Storybook purposes, and I want to use an Angular service (**ToasterService**) within it. The service has dependencies injected through its constructor (e.g., **Overlay**, **BreakpointObserver**).

The challenge is that the component is used exclusively for Storybook, and I prefer to keep it within the story file without creating a separate component file.

Here's a simplified version of the relevant code:

```
// ... (imports)

export const Toaster: Story<ToastersComponent> => {
  ...,
  render(args) => ({
    props: {
      ...args,
      generateToaster: ()=> {
        alert("Generate Toaster !")
        // need to call toasterService.show()
      }
    },
    template: `
      <div>
        <button (click)="generateToaster()"> Show Toaster</button>
      </div>
    `,
});
```

How can I correctly inject the `ToasterService` within the Storybook story, considering it's only used for Storybook and I'd like to avoid creating a separate component file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and straightforward way is to create a dedicated component that can inject our service ( as sample as this :)

```
// ... (imports)



@Component({ // an inner-component for more readable story
  selector: 'toasters-component',
  template: ` <button (click)="showToaster()"> Show Toaster</c-button> `,
})
export class ToastersTestComponent {
  @Input() message: string = ''
  @Input() status: string = 'success'
  ... 

  constructor(private toasterService: MyToasterService) {}

  showToaster() {
    this.toasterService.show(this.message, this.status ... })
  }
}

...

export const Toaster: Story<ToastersTestComponent> => {
  ...,
  render(args) => ({
    props: {
      ...args,
    },
    template: `
      <div>
        <toasters-component [message]="message" .. > </toasters-component>
      </div>
    `,
});
```

Comment: let me know in the comments if you want the whole story code